# Getting undefined method published_changed error for my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a activerecord model. And I want to know how many attributes changed after the update call.

This is my code code for models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_profile,:class_name => 'Profile',:foreign_key => :first_profile_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :first_profile
  attr_accessible :first_profile_attributes
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => User
   before_update :perform_task
end
```

When I update or save User model, its the Profile model that gets saved first and I get empty attributes_changes hash when I am inside perform_task function. Ihave tried to use published_changed but I get undefined function error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `published_changed?` instead.

Comment: this is what i wrote and i still got the undefined method published_changed? error self.first_profile.published_changed?